# How to pass MongoDB collection name as parameter in AWS Glue job script?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, collections, parquet

I have created AWS Glue Job script to move the mongoDB collection to S3 as parquet format, it's working fine, but i want to pass the collection name as parameter, How to do that? is there any possible to achive this?

I have tried import argparse but not working.